# adjective translation help used in scenarios of security and satisfaction

Tags: adjectives, translation

There's a word I'm trying to see if there is a translation for. See the following scenarios.

> 1. A young man is introduced to his girlfriend's parents for the first time. He is well-off, looks reliable and the safety and assurance the parents feel with him as a person...

The adjective would describe all of the last sentence. This same word is used to describe the following as well:

> 2. Someone writing a test has prepared well for the test. He/she feels a certain way about the test, like being fully satisfied and confident about the test he/she will be writing or has written.

Assurance was also an adjective I was considering. Or is there different specific adjectives one would use in these different scenarios? 1.An attractive young man you feel safe having your daughter spend the rest of her life with who seems reliable 2. feeling you get when you write a well written test. Either or method of answering will be appreciated. Comments on the adjectives I mentioned would also help, as people can vote it up or down and I can get a general consensus.

Someone has described that word like this:

> One can use it for something that can be used/benefited from life-long so there is no fear or worry.

In fact let me summarize the different places this adjective can be used:

> when one has a lot of possessions or money, they feel this way. A bit like 'secure about one's life'

As this word is korean here's a bit of background in terms of the culture

> Korean parents that are from the older generation love having sons. They say that having a son is like a symbol of strength, and (insert desired adjective here to indicate security and flourishing/producing of crops and income etc)

here's some word others have used: desireable, confident. 
So in total: 
1. a son/ son-in-law that is someone that is reliable and you feel would protect your daughter and her reputation in life. 
2. feeling you get when you wrote a test well.

As a added plus: (and some extra interesting info if it helps in any way) this also is the adjective people say they feel after they had a full meal. When they regain their strength and they don't need anything else indicating satisfaction and strength in being full? xD

So it's a long read, I tried to be specific and detailed but let me know if there is any other info I should provide. 
The word is 'din-din' or emsems typed on a korean keyboard.

In short one can say :

> I feel ________. 
>   I'm satisfied, confident about the future, and happy how things are going. 
>   He is _______. 
>   implying satisfaction with the person, trust that good will come in the future with the relationship with this person and that you feel he is the guy that can sort things out and you can depend on

Comment: Please help me improve how to ask this question. It can still be modified. But please let me know what I should change in my question rather than downvoting and leaving without any input.

Comment: Btw, "There's a word **for which** I'm trying to see if there is a translation."

Comment: Rather metaphorically, I'd call the man a bankable asset. Asset because it's worth having him and bankable because you can rely on him at all times to take care of you.

Comment: What is wrong with *assurance* that makes you want something else? What is it about *desirable* and *confident* that has made you reject them? You need to provide positive guidance toward something by at least providing negative guidance against these others. I have a possible answer about how one feels after a good meal, and it may apply to elsewhere too, but without some rationale it's essentially random.

Comment: [...] the safety and assurance the parents feel with him as a person. That way of writing this sounds funny to me. The parents feel she (the daughter) is safe and they are reassured by that. They are reassured their daughter is safe with him. The daughter thing and the test thing are completely different...

Comment: @Kris: there's a word I'm trying to see if there's a translation *for*. It's stated like that in my paragraph :]

Comment: @Jason Bassford desirable can be applicable to anything. It's just too large. It can be desirable for so many different reasons. The feeling I'm trying to portray is one of being protected and a secure kind of satisfaction. This can be desirable, but so can so many other things. Confident on the other hand, feels like an attitude towards something or about something rather than that full satisfaction feel I'm looking for.

Comment: @Lambie both the test and the daughter thing has one thing in common: both indicate security of success, satisfaction in something and a confidence, one that is such that it is so great that it enables one to take a risk for the future that would result from this, or rather, that introduces a positive future prospect,  in mind.

Comment: @esu security of success is not idiomatic. You mean the assurance of success. And, I repeat, (as I often have to), we say in English to be reassured of something. "The father felt reassured; he knew his daughter was safe with the young man."

Comment: I have shown how you can avoid ending a sentence in a preposition.

Comment: Does "a sense of reassurance" serve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the idiom/phrase/description you are looking for is **"to have all (of one's) bases covered"**.  Such an idiomatic situation is conducive to the confidence/assurance/satisfaction you describe. It means something along the lines of "every contingency detail has been met or satisfied completely".

Example:

> He had just met her parents, and to no surprise they really took a
>   liking to him. After all, **he did have *all* of his bases covered**
>   in their eyes. (meaning he met *all* of their expectations)

Unlike a true idiom there is quite a bit of variability in how the phrase is used depending on the situation or the tense etc., but the same idea is stated - to have all the bases covered.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+all+the+bases

Comment: With regard to this answer, I know that it implies that all the conditions are satisfied. But isn't there perhaps a feeling/ tendancy to favor someone even based on the risk (as in the case of the husband. They do not know if he will actually be a good husband since they are not married yet. But the assurance even in face of uncertainty... it isn't the same thing because although I may have a perfect situation, I may feel uncomfortable about it or distrust the perfectness of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

> The feeling I'm trying to portray is one of being protected and a secure kind of satisfaction.

This reminds me of being held by a parent, but *safe* isn't an appropriate word in the context of writing a test, and you don't think that *secure* fits.

I would suggest [**comfortable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comfortable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 a** : free from vexation or doubt • *comfortable* assumptions
>   • Lamb was *comfortable* in his ignorance of what he did not choose to know.
>  —James Mason Brown
>
> **b** : free from stress or tension • a *comfortable* routine • stayed at a *comfortable* distance from the crowd

It imparts the same sense as having a *safety blanket*. Some variations are **comforted** and **comfortably**.

So:

> A young man is introduced to his girlfriend's parents for the first time. They were comforted by his demeanour.
>
> Someone writing a test has prepared well for the test. They feel comfortable about writing it.
>
> Having lots of possessions and money, they felt comfortable with their life.
>
> After eating a big meal, he was comfortably full.